# Why am i getting this error (TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable) after the first iteration of my for loop?

Tags: python, h5py

The following code i wrote, will run one iteration with no problems. However i want it to loop through all of the values of x (which in this case there are 8).  After it does the first loop through, when it goes to the second, i get an error on this line (t = f[x]['master_int'])

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Hd5_to_KML_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    t = f[x]['master_int']
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable
```

So it only outputs results (a .csv file and a .kml file) for BEAM0000.  I was expecting it to loop through and output the two files for all 8 beams.  What am I missing, why won't it loop through the other beams?

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import csv
import simplekml
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Creating a KML from an HD5 file')
parser.add_argument('HD5file', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
HD5file = args.HD5file

f = h5py.File(HD5file, 'r')
beamlist = []
for x in f:
    t = f[x]['master_int']
    for i in range(0, len(t), 1000):
        time = f[x]['master_int'][i]
        geolat = f[x]['geolocation']['lat_ph_bin0'][i]
        geolon = f[x]['geolocation']['lon_ph_bin0'][i]
        beamlist.append([time, geolat, geolon])     
    file = x + '.csv'
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)
        wr.writerows(beamlist)      

    inputfile = csv.reader(open(file, 'r'))
    kml = simplekml.Kml()       

    for row in inputfile:
        kml.newpoint(name=row[0], coords=[(row[2], row[1])])
        kml.save(file + '.kml')
```

Comment: You are using the variable `f` to refer to two different files.

Comment: could you elaborate please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the context manager here:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
```

it reassigns to `f`, so when you try to access a value like `f[x]`, it tries to call `__getitem__(x)` on `f`, which raises a `TypeError`

replace this block:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(beamlist)
```

with something like:

```
with open(file, 'w') as fileobj:
    wr = csv.writer(fileobj)
    wr.writerows(beamlist)
```